# Swap size LIMITED to RAM size

Tags: linux, memory, raspberry-pi, swap

I've created a swap file of 4.3GB. Made it a swap file with `mkswap` and then mounted it at boot. Now... if I have done a  `free -m` of my system I got:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           461         98        363          0         13         49
-/+ buffers/cache:         35        426
Swap:          511          0        511
```

Why the swap size is limited to 512MB? (My RAM size!)
How can I increase that?
Thank you!

Comment: Post your method of creating the swap file (exact commands). I bet the issue lies there. How you mounted the swap file may also be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I retried doing the swap file with these parameters (that I thought I used before but..) and it worked.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/wherever/you/want bs=1024 count=4194304
```

Where `4194304` is `1024*4096(MB)`.